# Multiple Timers

Tags: c#, timer

```
    private void timer5_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("sendmail");
        timer5.Enabled = false;
    }


    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

               MessageBox.Show("timer2");
               timer2.Enabled = false;

               timer5.Interval = 5000;
               timer5_Tick(null, new EventArgs());
    }

    private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            MessageBox.Show("timer3");

           timer3.Enabled = false;
           timer5.Interval = 5000;
           timer5_Tick(null, new EventArgs());
    }

    private void timer4_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            MessageBox.Show("timer4");
            timer5.Interval = 5000;
            timer5_Tick(null, new EventArgs());

        timer4.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer2.Enabled = true;
        timer3.Enabled = true;
        timer4.Enabled = true;
        timer5.Enabled = false;
 }
```

Above code works: 5secondwait>message-timer2,message-sendmail(same time)> 5secondwait message-timer3,message-sendmail(same time)>5seconds>message-timer4,message-sendmail(same time) finish work.
Question is:5secondwait>message-timer2>5secondwait>message-sendmail>5secondwait>message3timer3>5secondswait>message-sendmail>5seconswait>message-timer4>5secondswait>message-sendmail. finish work.
How to make this?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, you may wish to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32251362/edit) your question to improve its formatting and to add an explanation as to what you are trying to do..

Comment: what you exactly want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just going to throw in a simple code snippet that might help you:

```
private async void DoStuff()
{
    MessageBox.Show("action1");
    await Task.Delay(4000),
    MessageBox.Show("action2");
    await Task.Delay(4000);
    //...
}
```